# Why if I select `Open Table` for temporary global table doesn't work in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ssms

I have an issue in Management Studio Express 2005.

If I select `Open Table` for a temporary global table:

[image]

Not works, the error appears:

[image]

But if I write

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.##tempResults
```

then the table content will appears.

[image]

There are any fix for this problem ?

I have SP4 for Management Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fix for this issue, other than:

(a) using a permanent table instead of a global ##temp table. What does the global ##temp table buy you over a permanent table? They both kill concurrency just as effectively.

(b) using Script Table As > SELECT TO > New Query Editor Window. It's a little less direct but you still don't have to type and you avoid the terrible habit of using Open Table in the first place (this places all kinds of unnecessary locks on the underlying table because you *could* choose to edit the data in a grid, pretending you're using Excel).

(c) moving past SQL Server 2005. In SQL Server 2008+ the menu option Open Table is gone, now there are two separate options, edit top n rows and select top n rows. The latter does (b).